# useMemo for string constants

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

in some code i have seen the below usage of useMemo.
is this valid? i've been wondering what is advantage of this and why can't we simply use const?

```
const id = React.useMemo(() => "sort_id", []);
```

Comment: It's an unperformant, unreadable nonsense. `useMemo` is useful mostly for deriving state where the derivation process is computation-heavy (in other words, caching expensive computations that are redone as other state changes). A string does *not* need it, since strings are compared by value, rather than by reference, at least from the language user's point of view. The only thing that's realistically happening there is invoking the entire `useMemo` mechanism to avoid constructing a string on every call, and I assure you the latter is more performant (and readable).

Comment: Second to @JohnSmith. Moreover, If you read react docs for this hook, it is not guaranteed that react will preserve the value anyway. It can "forget" previously memoized values sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const` gets reinstantiated on every render, whereas `useMemo` will hold the same reference until the component is unmounted/remounted.

Comment: so this is valid, and it is advisable to define constants like this in the functional components?

Comment: Well it depends on what you're trying to do. If you want a single value that never changes under any circumstances and must be instantiated inside your component, (a true "const") than yea, you could use `useMemo`. If you are populating that value from outside the component (a constants file for example) than it doesn't matter.

Comment: Just remember that react components (outside of hooks) are nothing more than functions that return other components. When the function goes out of scope, (ie. after the render has finished) any `const` goes out of scope and gets re-instantiated the next time the component gets run. The `useMemo` trick just makes it so the value stays in the hook between renders.

Comment: You can just define constants outside of the component instead of inside the component and you don't need useMemo if you do that.